# meta_query for an ACF checkbox field don't works correctly

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, troubleshooting

I got a problem with value = 0 for meta_query checkbox field:

```
$args = [
                'post_type'        => 'post',
                'post_status'      => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'   => - 1,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'test_field',
                        'value'   => 0,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            ];
```

This code works fine if value is 2,3 etc. But when I set meta_query value to 0 or 1 it works wrong and i get all posts which has not empty test_field in post.

How can i got only posts with value = 0 or 1?
i have tried change compare to IN or = but its not words for checkbox fields

Comment: As it is right now the question is not answerable. we can not guess what is in you DB and what should be the expected result. An edit with more context is needed if you want to get a useful answer

Comment: ... you say it is a checkbox but search for more than two values... You use an integer value for a `LIKE` search... things just do not make much sense right now

Comment: As i said i tried use another compare as '=' and 'IN' but it gives no result.
I want find all posts which has in custom field test_field value 0 or 1.
But if i set
 'value'   => 0,
or
 'value'   => 1,
query works wrong and don't display posts only with this value
if set 
 'value'   => 2,
or
 'value'   => 3,
it works fine with LIKE without any problems

Answer (score 0):

If you expecting a number as a value you can set the `type` parameter to `NUMERIC`.

Otherwise `0` is evaluated to `false`.

Then you can use `IN` comparison if you only want a set range.

```
$test_query = new WP_Query(
        [
            'meta_query' => [
                [
                    'key'     => 'test_key',
                    'value'   => [ 0, 1 ],
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                    'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );
```

Comment: That not works. WP_Query can't find any posts with this args, even if i set value to another arguments

Comment: Then your issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: problem is that chechbox fields works only with compare LIKE

Comment: I think thats why if i use get_field there is not numeric values or string in value, its a array.
3 checkboxs is checked
http://prntscr.com/kj7hab

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kj7pjg

Comment: Can you show us what values are saved in your database for your meta field. That will tell us exactly why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

ACF plugin store checkbox values as serialized array.

```
// array(0)
a:1:{i:0;s:1:"0";}
// array(0, 1, 2)
a:3:{i:0;s:1:"0";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;s:1:"2";}
```

> How can i got only posts with value = 0 or 1?

You can search for these posts surrounding value with `"`, but it's slow query. 
It will be better to store `test_field` as single value. If you do not want to resign from ACF checkbox, change your `$args`

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'test_field',
        'value'   => '"0"',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'test_field',
        'value'   => '"1"',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
),
```